# Deserialize unknown section into List or Dictionary

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have the following XML file:

```
<Error>0</Error>
<Description>1</Description>
<Document>
  <ObjectID>06098INF1761320</ObjectID>
  <ced>109340336</ced>
  <abstract>DAVID STEVENSON</abstract>
  <ced_a />
  <NAM_REC />
  <ced_ap2 />
</Document>
```

So I deserialize it on C# (4.0) with this objects structure:

```
        [XmlElement("Error")]
        public string Error { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Document")]
        public List<EDocument> LstDocument { get; set; }
```

So here's my issue: the element "Document" has unknown sub-elements: ObjectID, ced, etc., is there a way that I can deserialize those unknows elements into a List, Array, Dictionary or something to iterate with (something like this, it DOESN'T have to be exactly like this, I'm just guessing):

```
object.LstDocument[0].ListDocument.name; //to get the name
object.LstDocument[0].ListDocument.value; //to get the value
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

To add some extra clarification to my question:
The child nodes under "Document" element are unknown because they are variable, with this I mean that at a moment I could have "ObjectID" and "ced", in other moment they could be "ced","ABC", etc. I'm not sure which elements came there as child nodes, all I know is that they are elements (not attributes) and that they don't have any child-nodes inside them.

Comment: I'd imagine the only way to going to be to load this via `XmlDocument` and then iterate over the ChildNodes manually; the XML serializers for classes typically just care about the class structure.

Comment: Not sure I understand you correctly but couldnt u just insert ObjectId as a prop and set it to "" and not null? I do it to elements that does requiered but without elements,

Comment: Also take a Look at the difference between XmlAttribute and XmlElement. I think it help you,

Comment: Please take a look at my EDIT 1, I have added extra clarification.

Comment: Following the suggestion given by Tejs, I asked a new question in that direction, you can view it here with its answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534955/c-xml-treat-inner-xml-from-a-certain-element-as-string